# Creating new lines between ascii encoded strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

new coder here with what should be a pretty simple question:

I am trying to create a script which uses this code to add consecutive digits and convert them to ascii and print them:

```
x = '36 30 25 40 80 4
     37 30 25 40 80 4'
    
     40 30 25 40 80 4
nums = [int(n) for n in x.split()]
''.join(chr(sum(nums[i:i+2])) for i in range(0, len(nums), 2))
```

I want the output to be

> BAT CAT
>
> FAT

... but right now it is BATCATFAT

So how can I create a space between each new word?

I realize this is probably way overexplained so sorry.

Also I already think I know how to create a new line using a simple if / else loop to detect for empty lists

Comment: Do you know the size of each word? Is it fixed? (i.e. 3 characters) How do we know when a word ends and a new word begins?

Comment: A new word is signified by a new line.  And then a new line in the output will be signified by a break in the text, which i can search for by looking for "\n" i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
data = """36 30 25 40 80 4
37 30 25 40 80 4
40 30 25 40 80 4"""

lines = [x for x in data.split("\n")]
nums_list = [[int(c) for c in x.split(" ")] for x in lines]
char_list = [[chr(sum(nums[i:i+2])) for i in range(0, len(nums), 2)] for nums in nums_list]
word_list = [''.join(c) for c in char_list]

print(" ".join(word_list))
```

Perhaps not the most elegant, but it works:

```
BAT CAT FAT
```

Printing out the contents of each of the data transformations we took above:

```
> print(lines)
['36 30 25 40 80 4', '37 30 25 40 80 4', '40 30 25 40 80 4']

> print(nums_list)
[[36, 30, 25, 40, 80, 4], [37, 30, 25, 40, 80, 4], [40, 30, 25, 40, 80, 4]]

> print(char_list)
[['B', 'A', 'T'], ['C', 'A', 'T'], ['F', 'A', 'T']]

> print(word_list)
['BAT', 'CAT', 'FAT']
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but I actually need the words in this example 'BAT' and 'CAT' to print on the same line.  I apologize for wording it confusingly, but right now it is saying BATCAT and i just want it to print BAT CAT

Comment: @chillbro Here ya go